# Which distribution can given random variable have?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Let $$S=\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i$$

Assume that $X_i\sim \mathrm{Poisson}(2)\ \mathrm{iid}$. Furthermore assume that the $X_i$ are independent of $N$. Let $\mathbb E[N]=9$ and $Var(N)=10$.

Which of the following distributions can $N$ have:

Binomial,

Poisson,

negative Binomial

Because $\mathbb E[N]\neq Var(N)$ it is not possible that $N\sim Poisson$ I would say.

But how can I reason whether or not it is possible for $N$ to be (negative) binomially distributed?

Comment: Variance of binomial distribution is less than its mean so negative binomial is the only possible option. What does it have to do with $S$ though?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri This is only part (a) of an exercise. In part (b) I need to evaluate the probability that $N=3$. Now I don't really know why I would need the distribution of the $X_i$ here :D

Comment: Yeah, even in part $b$ you don't need $X_i$